# Small issue clearing an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small issue clearing an interval with Javascript.
I've searched for the mistake that I've made but I couldn't find any.

Variable declarations:

```
let i, interval;
let currentLoops = 0;
let settings = {
        amount:0,
        loops:0,
        speed:0};
```

Where i make my interval:

```
$('#start').click(()=>{
        getSettings();
        let interval = setInterval(setColorGrid, settings.speed);
});
```

How i tried to clear it:

```
if(currentLoops == settings.loops){
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("interval cleared");
        }
```

If you have any ideas/suggestions for this comment below.

Comment: `let` has no scope outside the click, you better move it outside to declare or change it to var

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `let` part from the event handler. It causes to create a handler function scoped `interval` variable which shadows the outer `interval` variable.

```
$('#start').click(() => {
     getSettings();
     interval = setInterval(setColorGrid, settings.speed);
});
```

Comment: better to declare it outside

Comment: I cant accept the answer yet but that was the issue... I really wonder how i didnt see that :D

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam it is declared outside

Comment: yeah i just meant that i agree it shouldnt be declared inside :).

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I declared it outside but i needed to declare it under certain conditions thats why i did that